Why does my USB drive not show its full capacity?
I've got a 32GB flash drive that is being detected properly in Linux, but only has 4.9GiB actually usable.
There is only one ext4 partition on it, taking up the entire drive.
I'm ~~99%~~ 100% sure the flash drive is not counterfeit/fake, but it is a few years old now.
I'm not sure what the discrepancy means, would simply repartitioning it help?
sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdd:
Disk /dev/sdd: 28.88 GiB, 31004295168 bytes, 60555264 sectors
Disk model: FLASH DRIVE     
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 0EB3F826-06DD-460E-9DDD-88B45C7871D6

Device     Start      End  Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdd1   2048 60555230 60553183 28.9G Linux filesystem

lsblk -f:
NAME        FSTYPE FSVER LABEL    UUID                                 FSAVAIL FSUSE% MOUNTPOINTS
...
sdd                                                                                   
└─sdd1      ext4   1.0            424bec54-d379-4029-8790-1b368bd29699    4.2G     8% /mnt
...

df -h /dev/sdd1:
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdd1       4.9G  379M  4.3G   9% /mnt

du -sh /mnt:
379M    /mnt

sudo f3probe --destructive --time-ops /dev/sdd:
F3 probe 8.0
Copyright (C) 2010 Digirati Internet LTDA.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.

WARNING: Probing normally takes from a few seconds to 15 minutes, but
         it can take longer. Please be patient.

Good news: The device `/dev/sdd' is the real thing

Device geometry:
            *Usable* size: 28.88 GB (60555264 blocks)
           Announced size: 28.88 GB (60555264 blocks)
                   Module: 32.00 GB (2^35 Bytes)
    Approximate cache size: 0.00 Byte (0 blocks), need-reset=no
      Physical block size: 512.00 Byte (2^9 Bytes)

Probe time: 3'34"
 Operation: total time / count = avg time
      Read: 446.7ms / 4815 = 92us
     Write: 3'33" / 4192321 = 50us
     Reset: 0us / 1 = 0us


try resizing FS by resize2fs. maybe your FS was created when partition was only 4.9Gb, then later partition was extended, but not FS.

resize2fs did the trick, thank you!

Perhaps the USB Stick is a fake one.
You can check by test software like:
H2testw

But maybe, thats a windows software.
Maybe you can resize the size of Partition or create a additional partition by the Linux tool gparted.

Definitely not fake. H2test2 is windows only, i've updated the post with f3 results
